# iterate a map in for loop in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi am using a ajax call to get a map. Its working fine.
I want to display the map value in a table only two `td` allowed remaining will move to next row

My code is here

My output is like this

[image]

I want to make this as two `td` per `tr`

```
s = s + "<tr class='fc-staff'>";
$.each( msg, function( key, value ) {
  alert( key + ": " + value );
   s = s + "<td >" + value
    + "</td> ";
});
```

Its working fine but all the values are in single `tr`.  I want something like this

```
for ( var j = 0; j < limit; j += 2) {
s = s + "<tr class='fc-staff'>";
for ( var i = j; i < j + 2; i++) {
  alert("value " + i + "/" + j+" val :"+msg[i,value]);
    if (msg[i] != undefined) {  
s = s + "<td >" + msg[i,value]
    + "</td> ";
}
}
    s = s + "</tr>";
```

**Note:** The above code i tried for list working fine as i except but dont know to do with map.
 Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to combine the two approaches. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/4Q8uQ/1/)'s a working fiddle.

```
s = "<tr class='fc-staff'>";
var count = 0;
$.each(msg, function(key, value) {
    if (count > 1 && count % 2 === 0) {
        s += "</tr><tr class='fc-staff'><td>" + value + "</td>";
    } else {
        s = s + "<td >" + value + "</td> ";
    }
    count++;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correct you want to iterate through the key/value pairs and put all the values in separated td's which. These td's you want in a tr. You could try something like:

```
var html;

var tr = $("<tr/>");

$.each( msg, function( key, value ) {

    tr.append($("<td/>").html(value));

});

html += tr.html();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
var counter=0;
s = s + "<tr class='fc-staff'>";
$.each( msg, function( key, value ) {
if(counter<2)
{
   ++counter;
   s = s + "<td >" + value   + "</td> ";
}
else
{
    counter=1;
    s = s + "</tr><tr class='fc-staff'>";
    s = s + "<td >" + value   + "</td> ";
}
});
s = s + "</tr>";
```